# CORS error when using Firebase Hosting and Cloud Run

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-run

I have a SPA with the following setup:

- Frontend: React deployed using Firebase Hosting
- Backend: GraphQL API written in Django deployed on Cloud Run

Everything works locally but when I deploy the app and try to make requests, I get a CORS error due to preflight missing allow origin header:

> Access to fetch at 'https://cloud-run-api-hash.a.run.app/graphql/' from origin 'https://project-id.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Using `django-cors-headers`, I have already added the Firebase domain to the `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` in my Django settings.

My `firebase.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/authenticated/**",  
        "run": {
          "serviceId": "cloud-run-serviceID", 
          "region": "us-central1"    
        }
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [ {
      "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
      "headers": [ {
        "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value": "*"
      } ]
    } ]
  }
}
```

My intention is to trigger the cloud run container after the user is authenticated and is routed to `https://project-id.web.app/authenticated`, but I'm not seeing any Cloud Run logs after I login to the app. Furthermore, when I try to send any HTTP requests I get the CORS error shown above. Not sure where went wrong here because I strictly followed the Cloud Run/Firebase Hosting documentation. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was with `django-cors-headers`. I put the allowed domains in `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` instead of `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` and it worked. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers), this setting was renamed. I still unsure why `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` doesn't work on Cloud Run though... it should work as an alias.